# Correct way to use Task.Run and Wait

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have the below block of code that is being launched by a timer:

```
private void CheckForScheduleItemsTimerOnElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
    if (CurrentlyProcessingMsgs)
        return;

    CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = true;

    var task = Task.Run(() => {
            CheckForScheduleItems.Process(_cancellationToken);
        }, _cancellationToken);

    task.Wait(_cancellationToken);

    CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = false;
}
```

Now the problem that I am having is that in some cases, the line

```
CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = false;
```

is not getting called.   It was my understanding that the Task.Wait was supposed to wait for the task to complete, then continue on, thereby resetting that flag.   But in some cases, that is not happening.   (Note: this timer is being managed by a service.)  What is happening is that the in the shutdown, I am checking the value of **CurrentlyProcessingMsgs** and sometimes it's still true after the task has completed.

The goal for this is to have multiple timers that are being fired off like the one shown above.   Each timer will do processing similar to what is shown above and I would like to run each process in a separate thread.   I was mistaken on my understanding of the CancellationToken, so in this instance, what would be the correct way to setup the timers and Tasks to run through these methods and have each on a separate thread?

Comment: For your timers question it depends on the timer you are using. Some timers built in to .NET automatically will use the thread pool to fire off the timer (the same thing Task.Run is doing). You need to show us which timer class you are using. You may be already doing what you want to do.

Comment: I am using the System.Timers.Timer class to fire off the timer.

Comment: Is the [`Timer.SynchronizingObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) value set on it? If it is `null` your timer is already creating new threads to run the timer ticks, you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: It's not being set.   So that means that my timer is firing on it's own thread already.   So I need to remove all the TPL Task stuff and mimic your second example within my timer elapsed method, correct?

Comment: You may want to wrap it all up in  a `try { ... } catch (OperationCanceledException) { ...}` I will update my answer

Comment: Scott, thanks for your time.   I do appreciate it.  That seems to so far have fixed my issue.  I really need to spend some more time reading up on the TPL stuff to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `_cancellationToken` is canceled a exception will be raised. If you want to make sure the flag is changed even if it is canceled or some other exception is raised by `Process` put the `CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = false;` in a try/finally block

```
private void CheckForScheduleItemsTimerOnElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
    if (CurrentlyProcessingMsgs)
        return;

    CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = true;
    try
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => {
                CheckForScheduleItems.Process(_cancellationToken);
            }, _cancellationToken);

        task.Wait(_cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = false;
    }
}
```

---

P.S. There is almost never a good reason to do a `Task.Run` then immediately wait on it. It would be a lot less overhead to just do the following which should have very similar logic.

```
private void CheckForScheduleItemsTimerOnElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
    if (CurrentlyProcessingMsgs)
        return;

    CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = true;
    try
    {
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        CheckForScheduleItems.Process(_cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = false;
    }
}
```

---

Here is a updated version with catching the exception.

```
private void CheckForScheduleItemsTimerOnElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
    if (CurrentlyProcessingMsgs)
        return;

    CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = true;
    try
    {
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        CheckForScheduleItems.Process(_cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        //If the task was canceled for some other reason than our token raise the exception.
        if(ex.CancellationToken != _cancellationToken)
            throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        CurrentlyProcessingMsgs = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are launching on one of the other threads then immediately blocking the current thread. You have no extra concurrent work going on here, all you are doing is using up extra ram for the extra call stack. Also on the token when you `Wait` is is going to forward on the `OperationCanceledException`, if you want a graceful stop to it you need to catch the exception.

Comment: I updated my question.   I am obviously misunderstanding some information on how to properly use the TPL.